# Python OpenCV plot multiple circles with a list of centre coordinates of an image

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv

1st, i wasnt sure if I should use pandas or numpy to read the list of coordinates from csv file?
2nd, when I try either I get stuck with OpenCV function cv2.circle(image,(x,y),25,(0,255,0)) and the reason why is because (x, y) only accept single integer number and the other reason is it only accept single int number with this function! My problem is I have multiple coordinates for this image and the other issue it i have float numbers!

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import math
dfa = pd.read_csv("filter_14.csv")
image = cv2.imread("image_1602.png")
x = dfa['project_image_X'].astype(int)
y = dfa['project_image_Y'].astype(int)
cv2.circle(image,(x,y),25,(0,255,0))
cv2.imshow('test image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)**
```

This is the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "image_print.py", line 23, in 
cv2.circle(image,(x,y),25,(0,255,0))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 131, in wrapper
raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to " "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: No screenshots of code please. [Edit] your question with the code as text.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without the content of your csv file, but it looks like you are passing a whole series to draw one circle instead of just one (x, y) value pair.
Try looping through all the values in the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import math
dfa = pd.read_csv("filter_14.csv")
image = cv2.imread("image_1602.png")
x = dfa['project_image_X'].astype(int)
y = dfa['project_image_Y'].astype(int)
for idx in dfa.index:
    x, y = dfa.loc[idx, ['project_image_X', 'project_image_Y']]
    cv2.circle(image,(x,y),25,(0,255,0))
cv2.imshow('test image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)**
```

If the problem persists, it would be helpful to see a sample of the csv file.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosMelus i've solved this differently by pulling the data twice seperately but i'll try your method as well ... Thanks!

Comment: Is there no faster way than iterating through the list? Seems like an oversight.